# How can I change the owner of a print job in Java

Tags: java, printing

Is there a way to set the print job owner when printing from a Java program?

From what I have been able to find, I think this may not be possible for security reasons - that doing so means I can impersonate another user.

thanks - dave

Comment: You should probably specify the OS you're working on

Comment: @fvu - any O/S. We write a library that others use so this will be functionality we provide regardless of platform. Unfortunately I can't find anything in the Java printer API that lets you set this.